# How to test dataLayer events implemented in Ruby code in Google Tag Manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

There are a few events that have been implemented in Ruby in our website. When previewed within Google Tag Manager the events are not firing or visible. Javascript implemented data layer events are firing and showing up in GTM with no issues. What am I missing?

Within Google Tag Manager I clicked preview to connect the website and clicked on various parts of the ruby implemented features to trigger tracking events.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is a backend language. Looks like you're trying to use front-end GTM with it.

Either stop paying any attention to Ruby and shift your attention to JS+GTM completely or switch to using server-side GTM. But no, don't switch to server-side GTM. That would most likely be overcomplicated.

If you really need to initiate analytics events from Ruby, you can. But you need to have a front-end intermediary listening to those events and translating them to the dataLayer. For this, you don't need any GTM/GA related libraries on the Ruby side, just communicate your payload as you normally do with the front-end.